# NSAttributedString clicks

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring

I would like to have an attributed string in a `NSTextView`. The attributed string has 3 lines, each one a different color and no underline. I want to be able to click (or double click) on each line, which would print out the line number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the addAttribute:value:range of NSMutableAttributeString to assign the click behaviour to your attributed string.

According to the documentation : [Attributed String](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004903-SW2). When your string is clicked, it should call clickedOnLink:atIndex: of TextView class or textView:clickedOnLink:atIndex: in the TextView Delegate.

Like this (coded on the browser, beware of errors )

```
NSMutableAttributedString* str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"Clickable String"];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [str length]);   
[str beginEditing];
[str addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"The value of your attr String" range:range];
[str endEditing];

[textBox setAllowsEditingTextAttributes: YES];
[textBox setSelectable: YES];
[textBox setAttributedStringValue: str];
```

Comment: I can obtain the behaviour of a link. My problem is that I need three lines with three different colors (I can change the color using setLinkTextAttributes:). When I try your code, I get [NSTextView setAllowsEditingTextAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance