# No visible @interface for NSApplication declares the selector openURL

Tags: objective-c

im quite new to Objective C, and i have not worked with the MVC system before.

I am trying to redirect to a URL via default browser, here is the relevant code:

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

...

- (IBAction)about:(id)sender;

...

@end
```

Declaring the action

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate

...

- (IBAction)about:(id)sender {

    NSURL *web_url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com/"];
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] openURL:web_url]; // error location
}

...

@end
```

implementing the action on button click about:

IDE error: No visible @interface for NSApplication declares the selector openURL

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: `IBAction` in App Delegate ? You should put the `IBAction` in view controller / view .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might be confusing iOS and OS X here. Your error message relates to:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] openURL:web_url];
```

and is saying that `NSApplication` has no method called `openURL:`. On iOS the `UIApplication` class has such a method, and on OS X the `NSWorkspace` class has such a method. Given your use of `NSApplication` I'm guessing you want the OS X case and so should be using:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:web_url];
```

Comment: The UIApplication's openURL from iOS is executed on the appDelegate, where is the NSWorkspace's openURL executed?

Comment: I found out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303485/nsattributedstring-clicks and I could solve what I wanted. My comment might not be useful and I might delete it soon, just in case you want to delete yours.